# Does the classifying map of a fibre bundle only depend on the transition functions?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, fiber-bundles, classifying-spaces

Does the classifying map of a fibre bundle only depend on the transition functions?

Precisely,

Let $\xi$ and $\eta$ be two fibre bundles over $B$, whose transition functions are same, both of their structure groups are $GL(\mathbb{F}^n)$, for $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C}$ or $\mathbb{H}$. The fibres of $\xi$ and $\eta$ may be different.

Let $f:B\to G_n(\mathbb{F}^\infty)$ be the classifying map of $\xi$.  Let $g:B\to G_n(\mathbb{F}^\infty)$ be the classifying map of $\eta$.

Does $f=g$?

Comment: As stated, you haven't provided any kind of relationship between the two fiber bundles.

Comment: Okay, now the answer is yes, provided that you replace "equals" with "is homotopic to" as I've mentioned in the comments to several of your other questions in this vein. Classifying maps are only well-defined up to homotopy.